# Having issue on Appending ONLY new Array Items Into a Dynamically Loaded Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append New Valuse from User inputs on click event and I am using following Mark up and code to do this.BUT because of using `.each()` the table is loading again and again with duplicated valuses. Can you please let me know how Can I stop this and Add (append) only the new inserted values

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="compValues">

    </tbody>
</table>

 var compareData = [];
 var data = {
            compItem1 : uName,
            compItem2 : uLName,
            compItem3 : uIimage,
            compItem4 : memberType,
            compItem5 : planTarget,
            compItem6 : selectedPlan,
            compItem7 : selectedSTime,
            compItem8 : historicDis,
            compItem9 : projectsNumber,
            compItem10: projectsCost,
            compItem11: projectsRoads,
            compItem12: projectsPhase
 };
        compareData.push(data);

 $.each(compareData, function (index, item) {
     var eachrow = "<tr>"
                 + "<td>" + item["uName"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["uLName"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["uIimage"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["planTarget"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["selectedPlan"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["selectedSTime"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["historicDis"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["projectsNumber"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["projectsCost"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["projectsRoads"] + "</td>"
                 + "<td>" + item["projectsPhase"] + "</td>"
                 + "</tr>";
     $('#compValues').append(eachrow);
     });
```

Thanks

Comment: Your iterating over the list for each element, this is probably giving you 11 outputs for each. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thanks Petro I already mentioned that this is happening because of using the .each() but how can I solve the issue?

Comment: what are you doing with your var index

Comment: Try using your own function instead of each(). I'm not even sure why each is the best solution for what your doing anyways. Any reason in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a unique key or id for the item you can just check if it's anywhere in the table already by adding it as an id for the tr and just checking in the code if it's already there with something like:

```
//if the unique key or id is uName, then do something like this
if ($('tr#' + item["uName"]).length === 0) {
    var eachrow = "<tr id='"+ item[uName] +"'>"
             + "<td>" + item["uName"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["uLName"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["uIimage"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["planTarget"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["selectedPlan"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["selectedSTime"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["historicDis"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["projectsNumber"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["projectsCost"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["projectsRoads"] + "</td>"
             + "<td>" + item["projectsPhase"] + "</td>"
             + "</tr>";
    $('#compValues').append(eachrow);
}
```

Comment: Hi triangulito thanks for reply but this is getting very complicated! what do you mean by unique key or ID? I am not getting anything from database!

Comment: I mean if you have the id that the database creates or if the uName is unique for every item or something like that.